# Adding Checkbox to Canvas

Tags: java, android, checkbox

Hi so is there a way to add a checkbox to a canvas? its methods are almost limited to the draw_*_*_ (drawcirlce, drawrectangle) but is there away to add a button/checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a **Button/Checkbox** to your **canvas**. Create a layout **XML** file, add your custom view there and add the **Button/Checkbox** there too.